# Hiding and Unhiding Frames with the use of a Checkbox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have deleted my previous posts as unusable for OS and would like to start over. As per Kate I have added code that I have tried along with the results. As per Bryan I have shortened script down to a minimal of 1 Checkbox and 1 mainframe and 3 additional frames. Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Attached is the code I have used.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Frame
root=Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("400x200")


##Option 1  PRODUSES LINE 14 OBJECT IS NOT CALLABLE #####
#class HideFrames():
        #def __init__(Frame):
                #self.Frame = Frame()
        #def HideFrames_info():
            #def Hide():
                #if cl is 0():
                    #Frame3.Hidden = True
                #if c1 is 1():
                    #Frame3.Hidden = False



##  Option 2 PRODUCES NO ERROR CODES But the code but will not work #####

class HideFrames():
        def __call__(self):
            self.Frame = Frame()
        def HideFrames_info():
                def Hide():
                        if cl is 0():
                                Frame3.Hidden = True
                        if c1 is 1():
                                Frame3.Hidden = False

#########################################

cb_var1 = tk.IntVar()
frame1 = Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame2 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4 = Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")


label = Label(frame3, text="FRAME 3", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = Label(frame4, text="FRAME 4", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")

c1 = Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Check to SHOW Frame 3   Uncheck to HIDE Frame 3", variable=cb_var1) 
c1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")


app = HideFrames()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start. 2 big issues: You need to use the `get()` method to check the value of a tkinter variable, and you need to make the function run when checkbutton is triggered using the `command` argument. Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def frame3_disp():
    if cb_var1.get():
        frame3.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
    else:
        frame3.grid_forget()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Dental Milling Machines")
root.geometry("400x200")

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, height = 150, width= 150, relief= tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="blue")
frame2 = tk.Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame3 = tk.Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")
frame4 = tk.Frame(frame1, height = 150, width= 150, relief= tk.RAISED, bd=8, bg="lightblue")

label = tk.Label(frame3, text="FRAME 3", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")
label = tk.Label(frame4, text="FRAME 4", fg="red")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, pady= 1, sticky= "W")

frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")
frame4.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=2,sticky="NW")

cb_var1 = tk.IntVar()
c1 = tk.Checkbutton(frame2, text = "Check to SHOW Frame 3   Uncheck to HIDE Frame 3", variable=cb_var1, command=frame3_disp)
c1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady= 1, padx= 5, sticky= "W")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This worked exactly as anticipated but I ran into a problem. When I added command to hide frame 4 and run program the frames do not default to hidden. I need to check and uncheck for frame(s) to be hidden. Also how do Vote to get you points for your help. I will edit after I send this comment